# Why are my pictures rotating (Flexslider or Slick)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, flexslider, slick.js

I tried to use FlexSlider and Slicky, but the same problem is happening on each side : my portrait pictures are displayed in the wrong way.

[image: portrait is rotated without any reason]

As you can see, the photo is taken in portrait mode when you open it directly with a photo viewer:

[image: the file in raw mode]

Do you have any idea of what's happening? Is it a viewport's issue?

Here is my code, very simple:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo Selector</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/flexslider/flexslider.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="slider">

      <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="my-portrait.png" alt="" />
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js""></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
      { 
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({});
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: need code to be able to help

Comment: Sorry, I just added my code. It's the simplest code we can imagine to display a flexslider, nothing very interesting. Except: it works fine with landscape pictures.

Comment: This is actually a super infuriating issue with Exif data. You can learn more about the [JS plugin here](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js). The The exif data contains the rotation, but web browsers do not parse or handle this data. The pixels need to be rotated in some way or another.

Comment: Wow it's crazy, thank you so much for the help. I would never have thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing this in the question's comments:

> This is actually a super infuriating issue with Exif data. You can learn more about the JS plugin here. The The exif data contains the rotation, but web browsers do not parse or handle this data. The pixels need to be rotated in some way or another - John Pavek

I rotated my images in Preview (macOS) around until they were properly oriented, and saved. The images appeared correctly in Slick. I haven't tried it in any Windows or Linux applications. Definitely not a long term solution, but at least it helps until (if and when) the bug is fixed in the Exif plugin.